# WHY can i not use if then with count() variable in MSQL

Tags: mysql

Srr can someone help me
i have next query for giving me the number of rows in a table

```
SET @UUIDTEST2 = 100;
SET @TESTNUMBER = 0;
SELECT @UUIDTEST2;
SELECT @UUIDTEST2 := count(*) from `swennenhome`.`tb_ElectrititeitLog` ;
SELECT @UUIDTEST2
```

This works BUT, when i add a if END IF Like this

```
SET @UUIDTEST2 = 100;
SET @TESTNUMBER = 0;
SET @TESTNUMBER = 0;
SELECT @UUIDTEST2;

SELECT @UUIDTEST2 := count(*) from `swennenhome`.`tb_ElectrititeitLog` ;
if  (@UUIDTEST2 = 0) then
   SET @TESTNUMBER = 5;
end if ;
SELECT @UUIDTEST2
```

i receive always a SQL syntax error.
I have be searching on google for 2 day's now and can't find the problem or a solution.

Comment: **Never say “I got an error” without telling us what the error is.**  Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Answer (score 0):

[IF statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) can be used in compound statement **only**.

Rather than [IF function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if).

```sql
-- ...
SELECT @UUIDTEST2 := IF(count(*), count(*), 5) 
    from `swennenhome`.`tb_ElectrititeitLog`;
SELECT @UUIDTEST2;
```

But in your case, you may avoid using IF:

```sql
-- ...
SELECT @UUIDTEST2 := COALESCE(NULLIF(count(*), 0), 5) 
    from `swennenhome`.`tb_ElectrititeitLog`;
SELECT @UUIDTEST2;
```

Comment: Really tx for your answer.